# Access all accounts in which are in Gerrit server

Tags: java, gerrit

I am implementing some automation framework on gerrit server

I was trying to pull all the users using the below api

`gerritApi.accounts().query()` // it is giving not implemented exception

`gerritApi.accounts().suggestAccounts().get()` // it is giving static list of 100 users whereas the requirement is to fetch all the users in gerrit server

Is there anyway to get all the users under Gerrit server
I am even fine with that project level, meaning if fetching all the users which are working under project/group.

FYI: I am using below gradle dependency

```
implementation 'com.urswolfer.gerrit.client.rest:gerrit-rest-java-client:0.9.5'
```